# Geometric distinction between real cubics with different Galois group?

Tags: galois-theory

The following Cubics have 3 real roots but the first has Galois group $C_3$ and the second $S_3$

- $x^3 - 3x + 1$ (red)
- $x^3 - 4x + 2$ (green)

Is there any geometric way to distinguish between the two cases? Obviously graphing this onto the real line does not help.

[image]

It is not clear to me why you cannot transpose the red dots but you can transpose the green ones.

Comment: The discriminant tells the story; if the discriminant is a square, then the Galois group is $C_3$; if the discriminant is not a square, then the Galois group is $S_3$.

Comment: I think it largely comes down to what counts as "geometric". I could very well imagine there being some sort of high-powered arithmetic geometry explanation for the difference, but I don't think such an explanation (if there is one) would give any sort of visualizable clues as to whether a given cubic has $C_3$ or $S_3$

Comment: If the discriminant is square does that correspond to some lattice being square? I don't think so. I want to construct a geometric object from an arbitrary cubic (maybe some restrictions, but certainly not knowing their Galois group beforehand) that will show what is happening.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to expect that the set of real points tells you the full story in an arithmetic situation. For example, can you tell that $\pi$ is transcendental but that $\sqrt{10}$ isn't from looking at their relative positions on the number line?

One thing you can do which (depending on your tastes) could count as geometric is looking at [Frobenius elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism).

**Proposition:** Let $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial. Suppose that for some prime $p$ not dividing the discriminant, $f$ splits into irreducible factors of degrees $d_1, d_2, ... d_k$. Then there is an element of cycle type $(d_1, d_2, ... d_k)$ in the Galois group of $f$.

Hence you can find a transposition in the Galois group (and show that the Galois group is $S_3$) by finding a prime $p$ relative to which $f$ splits as the product of a linear and an irreducible quadratic factor. (This is completely analogous to the situation over $\mathbb{R}$: one might say that complex conjugation is the "Frobenius element at infinity.")

Geometrically, instead of looking at the real points of the scheme $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}[x]/f(x)$, we look at points over finite fields. But from a scheme-theoretic point of view all of these points are included in the geometry of the "arithmetic curve" $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}[x]/f(x)$.

The [Frobenius density theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem) even guarantees that the converse holds: for every cycle type in the Galois group there is a prime $p$ realizing that cycle type.

Comment: so because $x^3 - 4x + 2 \equiv (x + 1)(x^2 + 4x + 2) \pmod 5$ this polynomial has a transpose (and thus Galois group $S3$) and presumably $x^3 - 3x + 1$ modulo every prime always factors completely or doesn't factor at all (I guess it would never factor until I found) $x^3 - 3x + 1 \equiv (x + 3)(x + 4)(x + 10) \pmod {17}$. On the other hand $x^3 - 4x + 2 \equiv (x+39)(x+46)(x+49) \pmod {67}$. So it seems like you have to actually check *every* prime until you find one.. and that will never end if your polynomial is cyclic.

Comment: @quanta: yes, if you can't find a transposition then that doesn't give a proof that the Galois group is $C_3$, just evidence. But as the comments say, that's what the discriminant is for.

Comment: Although I don't know what factoring over finite fields has to do with geometry, I found the term "Galois geometry" which I will try to read about hopefully to understand this.

Comment: I know the discriminant being square but that is an arithmetical thing, I don't know how to interpret it (or anything else) geometrically. Of course the discriminant can be seen as the determinant of a lattice but its squareness does not correspond to the squareness of the lattice.

Comment: @quanta: it's _arithmetic_ geometry. The idea is that we have a natural inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}[x]/f(x)$ which scheme-theoretically gives a branched cover $\text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}[x]f(x) \to \text{Spec } \mathbb{Z}$. The fiber of this map over $p$ is $\text{Spec } \mathbb{F}_p[x]/f(x)$ which describes the factorization of $f \bmod p$ and one is studying the "monodromy action" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monodromy) on this fiber when one studies Frobenius elements. In other words, it's an arithmetic analogue of a geometric (and topological) situation. Again, I think it is too...

Comment: ...much to expect a _classically_ geometric answer to an arithmetic question. You have to broaden your definition of geometry to see the geometry in this situation.

Comment: @Qiaochu, Just to be clear, what I was saying was that checking whether the integer $-4p^3-27q^2$ is a square or not is arithmetic. The things you have said about Spec, I think they are geometry but I need to read about the Frobenius and various other things before I can see it. By the way, thanks to your answer here I was able to understand what is being said in the question about quartics.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all cubics (with integer coefficients and three real roots) have Galois group $S_3$. What exactly is meant by "almost all" is a little technical, but the phrase can be made precise, and the result rigorously proved. One consequence is that if you start with a $C_3$ cubic and perturb the roots the tiniest little bit then with probability $1$ you now have an $S_3$ cubic. So just looking at the red dots can't help you: it's guaranteed that there is a set of green dots so close by that you wouldn't be able to distinguish them with an electron microscope.